# junit test case giving error

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, spring-annotations

I am new to writing test cases:

My controller is below :

```
 @RequestMapping(value={"/addschool" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public  final ModelAndView  addschool(@ModelAttribute("addschool") Pricing pricing, Map<String, Object> map,
                 Model model,  HttpServletRequest request) {

               System.out.println("Name=" + pricing.getName() + " age=" + request.getParameter("age"));

               ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(ADDSCHOOL);
                return mv;
           }
```

and my junit test case is this :

```
public class AddSchoolTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserManagementController controller;

    @Test
    public void testAddSchool() {

        ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
        HttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        Pricing pricing = new Pricing();
        String userName = "Laily";
        pricing.setName(userName);
        //ModelAndView mav= controller.handleRequest();
        try{
        ModelAndView mav= controller.addschool(pricing, model,null, request);
        //fail("Not yet implemented");
        assertNull(pricing);
        assertFalse(model.isEmpty());
        Assert.assertEquals("addschool", mav.getViewName());
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

}
```

but my problem is even if I will remove "add school" and put something else it wil show green but if I remove try and catch than in every case it wil give red. What is the problem.

Full stack trace is this

```
Error creating bean with name 'com.enbee.admin.controller.AddSchoolTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.enbee.admin.controller.AddInstiDeptLibController com.enbee.admin.controller.AddSchoolTest.controller; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.enbee.admin.controller.AddInstiDeptLibController] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)

aused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.enbee.admin.controller.AddInstiDeptLibController com.enbee.admin.controller.AddSchoolTest.controller; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.enbee.admin.controller.AddInstiDeptLibController] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 26 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.enbee.admin.controller.AddInstiDeptLibController] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pappu_kity says, removing the empty catch block exposes the fact that your `controller` field is null - and so probably hasn't been autowired.

To ensure that the field is autowired using `@Autowired` you need to run the test with the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` by annotating the `AddSchoolTest` class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:/path/to/applicationContext.xml" })
public class AddSchoolTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserManagementController controller;

    @Test
    public void testAddSchool() throws Exception {

        ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
        HttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        Pricing pricing = new Pricing();
        String userName = "Laily";
        pricing.setName(userName);
        //ModelAndView mav= controller.handleRequest();

        ModelAndView mav= controller.addschool(pricing, model,null, request);
        //fail("Not yet implemented");
        assertNull(pricing);
        assertFalse(model.isEmpty());
        Assert.assertEquals("addschool", mav.getViewName());
    }

}
```

Ensure that the `@ContextConfiguration` is set appropriately for the locations of your Spring config files.

Comment: Thanks Will but I am now getting this error Could not autowire field: private com.enbee.admin.controller.AddInstiDeptLibController

Comment: Because it's running as an integration test it will attempt to bring up the whole Spring application context and do all the wiring. Does your `@ContextConfiguration` specify the correct locations to your Spring config flles? Could you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Will, I post the full stack trace but Do I need to change something in spring-servlet also?

Comment: It looks as though Spring can't find `AddInstiDeptLibController` to autowire into your `AddSchoolTest`. The code in your original post is testing a `UserManagementController`. Have you changed this to a `AddInstiDeptLibController`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try changing

```
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(ADDSCHOOL);
```

to
`ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(addschool);`  or

```
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(pricing);
```

as it is in the `@ModelAttribute("addschool") Pricing pricing`
in your controller action .

I am not sure but just can see whether it works or not

Thanks.

Comment: final static String ADDSCHOOL = "addschool"; already this statement is there in the controller.

Comment: change ModelAndView mav= controller.addschool(pricing, model,null, request); to ModelAndView mav= controller.addschool(pricing, model,pricing, request); inside your try block to avoid null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

if it is red then your test case is falling, your catch block is empty, print the stack trace and see what is the problem  , upon exception your test case will fail.

Comment: It is giving ths on printing stack trace

Comment: It is giving ths on printing stack trace [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@406199 I think no exception is thrown but if I remove try and catch block then I am getting red and null pointer exception is thrown at ModelAndView mav= controller.addlibrary(pricing, model,null, request); ths statement . hw to remove ths exception.

Comment: yes you have empty catch block , so you are swallowing exception in  catch block. the cause for your exception will be your controller is not wired at all, hence you are getting nullpointer. i suspect that you might miss adding spring junit runner. check this link http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-transactional-junit4-test.html